# Intersection of set closed in probability with $L^1$ is closed in $L^1$

Tags: probability

In a proposition, an author has proved that some set $\Gamma$ is closed in probability, i.e. for convergence in probability. Later, in the proof of another proposition, I see
"
Since $\Gamma$ is closed for the convergence in probability, see {above} proposition, $\Gamma \cap L^1$ is closed in $L^1$.
", which I interpret as closed **for the $L^1$ convergence**.

I understand that $\Gamma \cap L^1$, i.e. elements of $\Gamma$ that are integrable, is still closed in probability. Since $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in probability, but the reverse implication is **not** true, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_n \in \Gamma \cap L^{1}$, $X_n \to X$ in probability and $X_n \to Z$ in $L^{1}$ then  $X_n \to Z$ in probability too, so $X=Z$ a.s. Hence, $Z=X \in \Gamma \cap L^{1}$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Got it, because $L^1$-convergence implies convergence in probability, closedness in probability **implies** closedness in $L^1$. I was seeing it the wrong way. Thank you!